# Auto refresh JPanel panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working on a program that should auto adjust a bar depending on the value I read from a file or array. I have placed two JPanel inside one another one is static and the other should get its values from the array/file. My problem is as you read the array or file I want to update the parameters of the JPanel. below is my example code.

```
int myvalues[] = {120,130,140,150,160,170,180};

for(int i = 0; i <= myvalues.length-1; i++){
    guagePanel.setSize(10,myvalues[i]);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

But the above is not getting the page refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sleep on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Instead, use a `SwingWorker` in combination with a `JProgressBar`, as shown in [*How to Use Progress Bars*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). If you're reading from a file, [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) may be convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You should update your panel on the Event Dispatch Thread. If you also call `Thread.sleep` on the EDT, your panel can not be repainted since the Thread is sleeping.

If you want to update the size each second you could consider using a [`Timer` (the Swing version, not the java.util version)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and update the size of your panel in the `ActionListener` of that Timer.

Not sure whether it is a typo in your code and you meant 'gauge' iso 'guage', but in that case there are [some really nice examples of gauges](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-component-library.html) available on the web

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. Its a typo, it should gauge I will give it a try and see how it goes.